# return a full dataframe based on partial colnames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame

```
dat <- read.table(text = 
               " 'A;B;T' 'C;D'     E      X
                  101     2.1     0.9     1
                  102     1.1     0.8     2       
                  103     2       1.5     2
                  104     2       1.5     0.5    
                  105     1.1     0.8     2  
                  106     1.1     0.8     2        
                  106     1.1     0.8     2   ", 
                  header=TRUE, check.names =FALSE)
```

Some columns have multiple names separated by `;` in the example `'A;B;T'  'C;D'`.

I want to use a reference vector that will assign and select at the same time the column and the final name in this case `"A" and "D"`. I want  also to maintain in my final data frame columns which have a correct single name.

Given a vector `v1<-c("A", "D")` to select and match colnames

I want to return this

```
  A   D   E   X
  101 2.1 0.9 1.0
  102 1.1 0.8 2.0
  103 2.0 1.5 2.0
  104 2.0 1.5 0.5
  105 1.1 0.8 2.0
  106 1.1 0.8 2.0
  106 1.1 0.8 2.0
```

Comment: You should explain the logic better. Why are the E and X columns also selected when you say you want to select and match based on `v1`?! And are those column names always single characters or can they be longer names so we have to split by `;`?

Comment: Does the question is now better explained and with enough details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` to extract the substring from the `names` of 'dat' and then assign the `names` with the newly extracted `vector`

```
library(stringr)
v1 <- str_extract(names(dat), paste(v1, collapse="|"))
i1 <- !is.na(v1)
names(dat)[i1] <- v1[i1]
dat
#    A   D   E   X
#1 101 2.1 0.9 1.0
#2 102 1.1 0.8 2.0
#3 103 2.0 1.5 2.0
#4 104 2.0 1.5 0.5
#5 105 1.1 0.8 2.0
#6 106 1.1 0.8 2.0
#7 106 1.1 0.8 2.0
```